# Anchor tag has wrong content-type for file thas is downloaded

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

so I'm creating a simple static site and I'm using ReactJs to create it. I wanted to implement a button that downloads a pdf file that I have in the resources folder of the project.

```
<div>
    <a className="button is-info"
        href="../resources/myFile.pdf" download>Download my CV
    </a>
</div>
```

I opened the file that was downloaded. It has a `.pdf` extension but is a `html` file with the content posted below, where the `bundle.js` probable has the code of the current site.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is added to the
      homescreen on Android. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/engage-and-retain/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <!--
      Notice the use of  in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>My online CV</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>
      You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.
    </noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/bundle.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

This is how I implemented the download, but as a response I'm getting a 1.6kb file. In the network tab in the developer tools response header returns a `content-type: text/html`.

I don't know how to continue with his issue and help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't getting an error page instead of the actual file? Also the content-type header is controlled by the server not the client so if there really is a wrong content type it would be caused by your server side code / server setup

Comment: @PatrickEvans Updated my question with the content of the downloaded file.

Comment: Then your server setup is wrong. Are you sure you setup the routes correctly in nodejs?

Comment: You can't convert html to pdf by simply giving it a `.pdf` extension

Comment: @charlietfl i know i wanted to download a pdf file and not a html file, that is my problem.

Comment: @PatrickEvans Do I have to set up a server just for one file download? I'm just running npm start, I haven't installed expressJs or set any routes for the project.

Comment: You either need to convert it on server or upload it as pdf using other conversion tool

Comment: upload from where? I have the file in my project and it's a pdf file.

Comment: `npm start` is usually a command to start nodejs server app, more than likely there is a script automatically setting up routes to your current page. You will need to modify that in order to include other files for access. Note expressjs or http-server was probably installed during whatever `npm install` or other process you used to setup your project